# Docker error when uploading image

Tags: docker, dockerhub

When I try to upload a docker image to the docker hub
using `docker push myImage`, I get the following error:

> lookup ***** on 127.0.1.1:53: no such host

Comment: Could you add more detail please

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is simple , 
just add to your host file 
at /etc/hosts this line

```
162.242.195.84  cdn-registry-1.docker.io
```

solution taken from here 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3203

Adding docker registry ip to the cdn url , fixed the issue , but  i had some errors , 
Changing my dns to google's dns fixed everything

at /etc/resolv.con change nameserver

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`